# Notice: Undefined index: on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, learndash

I've an error on my wordpress site : I just modify little thing I use Buddyboss and learndash 3.0 and this have appeared since I've modify something but I don't know what is this error
Notice: Undefined index: id_base in /www/zenmondrops_878/public/wp-content/plugins/widget-options/includes/widgets/display.php on line 414
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying a plugin is generally not a great idea. Whenever the plugin us updated, your changes are going to be removed.

From what it looks like, on line 414 in display.php you are referencing an array index that does not exist. If you want to resolve this, simply check that the array index exists before trying to access it. You can find a more detailed answer on how to do that here: ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: I just have uploaded I don't touch PHP at this time, it says me that it's in my side bar BUT nothing happens when i change something on buddyboss